# Delete duplicate entries

Tags: mysql

How to delete duplicate entries from database without using `distinct`, `group by`

```
Id.        Name              age         dob
1.           b.               11.        1992
2.           d.               14.        1967
3.           b.               11.        1992
```

Comment: In case of  rows with id 1 and 3 is there any preference as to which row must be kept and which row must be deleted?

Comment: what version of mysql are you using? P.S. this kind of question gets asked a lot...did you do any research?

Comment: Duplicate entries based on `Name`, `age` and `dob` ?

Comment: @Arulkumar duplicate entries Based on name

Comment: MySQL 5.6.16 @ADyson

Comment: "duplicate entries Based on name" ...it's quite common for 2 people to have the same name. If they have the same name, but different DOB then there's a good chance it's not the same person, don't you think? I'd expect a genuinely duplicate record would really be a combo of name, DOB, and possibly other fields - even same name & DOB can be different people in reality, if the population is large enough. I've seen it happen. You also might want to consider changing your validation procedures so that duplicates (however you want to define it) cannot be created in the first place

Comment: (P.S. storing the age is redundant because you have already stored the DOB. In fact it's actively a bad idea to store the age, because it becomes incorrect over time, and you don't want to have to go through every day and update the age records in case it's someone's birthday. What a waste of time. Just _calculate_ the current age whenever you need to see it, by using the DOB. You can even then calculate someone's age at _any_ point in time, not just right now.)

Comment: Yes @ADyson ,I will implement when get the right solution based on name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try this:
Suppose test is your table name :-

```
delete th 
from test as th 
where th.id IN (select id 
                from (select a.id  
                      from test as a 
                      left join test as b 
                          on a.name = b.name where a.id>b.id) AS T);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned duplicate entry based on `Name`, using `ROW_NUMBER()`, you can do with out `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.

The query will be:

```
DELETE FROM (
    SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Id) AS RN
    FROM Table
) AS Q
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: We  can not use order by,group by and distinct

Comment: @VibrateTasks why not? Is this some exam question with arbitrary pointless restrictions?

Comment: @ADyson brother according to condition I can't use group by, order by and distinct

Comment: @VibrateTasks condition of _what_? That was my point. Is this your homework? If so then I'd have hoped you'd done a bit more of your own research first to facilitate your learning, otherwise just spoon-feeding you the answer doesn't actually help you learn very much. Your question suggests a total lack of effort in this respect. Also in the original question you didn't mention that ORDER BY was banned, so this answer is perfectly legitimate from that point of view. Don't change the conditions as you go along, make it clear from the start

Comment: @ADyson yes it's my interview question.

Comment: @VibrateTasks right so you're relying on the expertise of others here and then will present it as your own, without apparently even having tried to do it yourself (if you did try, you didn't mention it or tell us what problem you had, so I have to assume). Nice. I hope it doesn't come back to haunt you when you start the job and it turns out you don't know how to do the real work. Of course you can always ask other people again, but there's a limit to how far that will carry you.